# How can I use the Tab key to indent in vim with SuperTab enabled?

Tags: vim, plugins, autocomplete, supertab

I've just enabled SuperTab in vim, and if I try to indent a blank line, SuperTab is attempting to insert strings. What I'd like, I guess, would be to have SuperTab offer completions *only* if there is non-whitespace to the left of the cursor.

I don't want to have to use Ctrl-V or Ctrl-Q or anything.

Comment: Do you happen to use Snipmate?

Comment: What you are asking for is a key feature of supertab. That's why I think your problem is caused by other plugins or mappings.

Comment: @timss - Yes, that was it. Out goes Snipmate!

Comment: @Zack No need to drop it, see my answer (and possibly accept it) :-)

Answer (score 11):

This could be caused by an old version of snipmate, update to the [forked version](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) maintained by Gargas.
It has quite a few dependencies so I'd recommend using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle) if you're not already using it.

*See comments to OP for more information.*

Answer (score 0):

msanders/snipmate.vim conflicts with supertab.

you can use ultisnips instead of Snipmate

https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips